# Ansible looses cookie content

Tags: cookies, ansible, uri

The program requires an authenticated session for executing api commands. This can be done by executing the login and using these cookies in the next calls. However the cookies are send with an empty value.

ansible 2.9.10

```
- name: Login to the portal
  uri:
    url: "http://localhost/login"
    method: POST
    body: "username=administrator&password={{ admin_portal_password }}"
    status_code: 302
  register: login

- name: Create vhost
  uri:
    url: "http://localhost/vhost"
    method: POST
    body: "{'identifier': 'default', 'hostSpecifiers': ['localhost'], 'ports': [{'port': {{ orch_port }}, 'ssl': false}], 'serverNamePassing': false, 'useVHostLogFile': true }"
    status_code: 200
    body_format: json
    headers:
      Cookie: "{{ login.set_cookie }}"
  register: vhost
```

**Login to the portal** program logs shows successful login
debug log ansible:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "cache_control": "private, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store", 
    "changed": false, 
    "connection": "close", 
    "content_length": "0", 
    "content_type": "text/html;charset=UTF-8", 
    "date": "Tue, 08 Sep 2020 09:36:33 GMT", 
    "elapsed": 0, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null, 
            "backup": null, 
            "body": "username=administrator&password=test", 
            "body_format": "raw", 
            "client_cert": null, 
            "client_key": null, 
            "content": null, 
            "creates": null, 
            "delimiter": null, 
            "dest": null, 
            "directory_mode": null, 
            "follow": false, 
            "follow_redirects": "safe", 
            "force": false, 
            "force_basic_auth": false, 
            "group": null, 
            "headers": {}, 
            "http_agent": "ansible-httpget", 
            "method": "POST", 
            "mode": null, 
            "owner": null, 
            "regexp": null, 
            "remote_src": null, 
            "removes": null, 
            "return_content": false, 
            "selevel": null, 
            "serole": null, 
            "setype": null, 
            "seuser": null, 
            "src": null, 
            "status_code": [
                "302"
            ], 
            "timeout": 30, 
            "unix_socket": null, 
            "unsafe_writes": null, 
            "url": "http://localhost/login", 
            "url_password": null, 
            "url_username": null, 
            "use_proxy": true, 
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    }, 
    "location": "http://localhost/login/ok", 
    "msg": "HTTP Error 302: ", 
    "pragma": "no-cache", 
    "redirected": false, 
    "set_cookie": "JSESSIONID=16CE38D04B94A630A60A50397A924155; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly, SESSION_IDENTIFIER=cb58a5fb-226b-4b4e-b8f6-5743d99266d8; Path=/; HttpOnly", 
    "status": 302, 
    "url": "http://localhost/login"
}
```

**Create vhost** program sees the cookies but skipping them because of NULL

```
DEBUG i.n.h.c.h.cookie.ServerCookieDecoder - Skipping cookie with null value
```

Answer (score 2):

It works by changing the first call to follow redirects and than using cookies_string instead of set_cookies

```
- name: Login to the portal
  uri:
    url: "http://localhost/login"
    method: POST
    body: "username=administrator&password={{ admin_portal_password }}"
    status_code: 200
    follow_redirects: true
  register: login

- name: Create vhost
  uri:
    url: "http://localhost/vhost"
    method: POST
    body: "{'identifier': 'default', 'hostSpecifiers': ['localhost'], 'ports': [{'port': {{ orch_port }}, 'ssl': false}], 'serverNamePassing': false, 'useVHostLogFile': true }"
    status_code: 200
    body_format: json
    follow_redirects: true
    headers:
      Cookie: "{{ login.cookies_string }}"
  register: vhost
```